Something is wrong with my React installation/ Node as a whole
I stopped practicing react for a few months and recently when I picked it up again, I was not able to even create a react app properly. There is a dependency conflict.
These are the errors whenever I ran the "npx create-react-app appname" command:
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: newapp1@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@19.0.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^19.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm error node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm error   @testing-library/react@"^13.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\chira\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-17T19_27_59_239Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\chira\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-17T19_27_59_239Z-debug-0.log
`npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^13.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 web-vitals@^2.1.0` failed

I've tried:

Downgrading react
Completely reinstalling react
Repairing node

This is also interfering with my mongodb installation
What else can I do?

CRA create-react-app is deprecated long time ago

Besides it's deprecated and you don't need to use it without a reason, the error literally says that the solution is --force or --legacy-peer-deps

If you're away from React for a few months and nothing working anymore is also pretty normal for React. Usually it means relearning at least something and replacing some tool for another. It's unfortunate it's been this way for quite a while.

I think it's because React has just updated to v19 last week and testing-library/react hasn't updated their dependency requirements yet.
In 2024, I would suggest creating a new React App using Vite. Try running this

npm create vite@latest

